# Flutter webview throws PlatformException(NSInternalInconsistencyException,InstanceManager does not contain an NSURL with identifier:65540, null, null)

Tags: flutter, dart, wkwebview

Here is my implementation using the official `webview_flutter` package version 4.2.2:

```dart
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    late final PlatformWebViewControllerCreationParams params;
    if (WebViewPlatform.instance is WebKitWebViewPlatform) {
      params = WebKitWebViewControllerCreationParams(
        allowsInlineMediaPlayback: true,
        mediaTypesRequiringUserAction: const <PlaybackMediaTypes>{},
      );
    } else {
      params = const PlatformWebViewControllerCreationParams();
    }

    final WebViewController controller =
        WebViewController.fromPlatformCreationParams(params);
    // #enddocregion platform_features

    controller
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
      ..setBackgroundColor(const Color(0x00000000))
      ..setNavigationDelegate(
        NavigationDelegate(
          onProgress: (int progress) {
            debugPrint('WebView is loading (progress : $progress%)');
          },
          onPageStarted: (String url) {
            debugPrint('Page started loading: $url');
          },
          onPageFinished: (String url) {
            debugPrint('Page finished loading: $url');
          },
          onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {
            debugPrint('''
  Page resource error:
  code: ${error.errorCode}
  description: ${error.description}
  errorType: ${error.errorType}
  isForMainFrame: ${error.isForMainFrame}
          ''');
          },
          onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
            if (request.url
                .startsWith('https://test.example.com/subscriptions/intent')) {
              var provider = context.read<StoreInfoProvider>();
              provider.setPaymentUrl(true);
              return NavigationDecision.prevent;
            }
            return NavigationDecision.navigate;
          },
          onUrlChange: (UrlChange change) {
            debugPrint('url change to ${change.url}');
          },
        ),
      )
      ..addJavaScriptChannel(
        'Toaster',
        onMessageReceived: (JavaScriptMessage message) {
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(content: Text(message.message)),
          );
        },
      )
      ..loadRequest(Uri.parse(widget.result == PaymentResults.success
          ? Strings.profileUrl
          : widget.result == PaymentResults.fail
              ? Strings.failedUrl
              : Strings.mainUrl));
    _controller = controller;
  }
```

I encountered this error in the iOS simulator while redirecting to the /subscriptions/intent url (keep in mind that the url has been altered for some reasons):

```
[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(NSInternalInconsistencyException, InstanceManager does not contain an NSURL with identifier: 65540, null, null)
#0 NSUrlHostApi.getAbsoluteString (package:webview_flutter_wkwebview/src/common/web_kit.g.dart:2799:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1 WebKitWebViewController._webView.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:webview_flutter_wkwebview/src/webkit_webview_controller.dart:242:48)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

What specifically has gone wrong?

Comment: can you provide the content of build method?

Comment: seems issue is in your url, so  once replace that url to google.com and check. as your used url is not working here on my browser too.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please ensure that the URL you are trying to load is valid and accessible.
2. Make sure you are using the latest stable version of Flutter.
3. Enable debug mode and check the logs for any additional error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it would help but i published a package which generally works well for most of WebView scenarios  in flutter

heres the link to it

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin_ios_android

Additionally the error message suggests that there is an issue with the integration between the Flutter WebView package (webview_flutter)  and the WebKit framework on iOS. So it might be worth trying out different versions of the package you are using